# Run task after view controller is deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider I have two `ViewController`'s `A` and `B`. `ViewController A` has few item and after selecting one of them, I push `ViewController` `B` displaying the selected items details. On the detail page I can set a timer for that item. Now what I want to achieve is when the user starts a timer for a particular item, he should be able to go back to `ViewController A`, select another item and start the timer of that item as well, and in case if he selects the same item for which the timer is already running it should display the remaining time. I have a method that gets executed for that particular item when the timer ends. I have got this to work but have an issue, when the users start a timer on the details page i.e `ViewController B` and navigates back, the timer stops, since the `ViewController` is deallocated. I want to know what approach is suitable for a situation like this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should write a separate class for managing the data, instead of doing it in view controllers. Have an instance of this class, or a singleton, live throughout the entire application's life cycle.

Comment: You can create timer in AppDelegate.

Comment: You can create background service and once view will disappear call method that time you can start BS.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate object that will store something like an **NSDictionary< NSString, NSDate>**. It will contain the id of selected item as a key and expiration date. When you navigate to **ViewController B**, you just need to check if expiration date exists for this item and proceed with countdown or create a new record in the dictionary and do the same.

Let's call it for ex. **OrdersStorage** and make it as a singleton. This is the simple solution and could be enhanced according to your requirements

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a Singleton structure to held your timer, like this:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

//Singleton Structure
class MyTimers {
    static let shared: MyTimers = MyTimers()
    var timers: [Timer] = []

    func addTimer(with timeInterval: TimeInterval, with repeats: Bool = false,and completion: (() -> Void)? ) {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: repeats){ thisTimer in
        thisTimer.invalidate()
        if let index = self.timers.index(of: thisTimer) {
            self.timers.remove(at: index)
        }
        completion?()
    }
    timers.append(timer)
  }
}

MyTimers.shared.addTimer(with: 2.0, and: {print("2  with: \(MyTimers.shared.timers.count) timers")})
MyTimers.shared.addTimer(with: 5.0, and: {print("5  with: \(MyTimers.shared.timers.count) timers")})
MyTimers.shared.addTimer(with: 10.0, and: {print("10 with: \(MyTimers.shared.timers.count) timers")})
MyTimers.shared.addTimer(with: 4.0, and: {print("4  with: \(MyTimers.shared.timers.count) timers")})
MyTimers.shared.addTimer(with: 8.0, and: {print("8  with: \(MyTimers.shared.timers.count) timers")})
```

Comment: Question is tagged `objective-c`.